# How do I override a model in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2.2

I want to override the model for an optional lastname.

**di.xml:**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress">
    <plugin name="aroundAddressValidation" type="Xxx\OptionalLastname\Plugin\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

**AddressAbstract.php:**

```
    <?php

    namespace Xxx\OptionalLastname\Plugin\Customer\Model\Address;

    class AbstractAddress
    {
        protected $_directoryData = null;
        protected $_eavConfig;

        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData, \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
        )
        {
            $this->_directoryData = $directoryData;
            $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        }

        public function aroundValidate(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress $subject, callable $proceed)
        {

            $errors = [];
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'firstname']);
            }

            //
            // if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            // $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'lastname']);
            // }

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getStreetLine(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'street']);
            }

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'city']);
            }

            if ($this->isTelephoneRequired()) {
                if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'telephone']);
                }
            }

            if ($this->isFaxRequired()) {
                if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getFax(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'fax']);
                }
            }

            if ($this->isCompanyRequired()) {
                if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCompany(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'company']);
                }
            }

            return $errors;
        }

        /**
         * @return bool
         * @since 100.2.0
         */
        protected function isCompanyRequired()
        {
            return ($this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'company')->getIsRequired());
        }

        /**
         * @return bool
         * @since 100.2.0
         */
        protected function isTelephoneRequired()
        {
            return ($this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'telephone')->getIsRequired());
        }

        /**
         * @return bool
         * @since 100.2.0
         */
        protected function isFaxRequired()
        {
            return ($this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'fax')->getIsRequired());
        }
    }
```

But it throws **Please check the shipping information** error. How do I overcome this error? If any modification in my code? If anyone knows please explain me.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution that worked for you.!!

Comment: can u please specify ur magento version

Comment: I am using version 2.2.3

Comment: I mentioned the answer below in this page @Manashvi Birla

Answer (score 4):

try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddres" type="Xxx\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddres" />
 </config>
```

Comment: its not a syntax for using plugin in M2

Comment: also tried preference.but no change in it

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public function aroundValidate(
\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress $subject, callable $proceed)
{

    $errors = [];
    if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'firstname']);
    }

    if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getStreetLine(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'street']);
    }

    if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'city']);
    }

    if ($this->isTelephoneRequired()) {
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'telephone']);
        }
    }

    if ($this->isFaxRequired()) {
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getFax(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'fax']);
        }
    }

    if ($this->isCompanyRequired()) {
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCompany(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'company']);
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors) || $this->getShouldIgnoreValidation()) {
        return true;
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: it throws same error like  required lastname

Comment: Ok, in the original class if you comment lines that's woks?

Comment: yes.it's working in core........

Comment: if plugin don't work you can try with preference, tell me if you nedd any help i'm here we can chat if you need

Comment: I'm already using preference .i can't override this file.it throws "last name required".In plugin method throws "Please check shipping information"

Comment: for the error Please check shipping information there is another file how throw this error

Comment: but the error came from overriding file

Comment: we can chat? its more simple

Comment: how to remove lastname validation in checkout page without any error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69203/discussion-between-mohamed-el-mrabet-and-mahalakshmi-m).

Answer (score 2):

Your di.xml is wrong if you want to override a class.

**In Magento there are two types of overriding:**

- One is Plugin
- Another is preference

**PLUGIN:**

Is used for changing the behavior of a method. See the details at [Magento developer documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html')

**Syntax:**

```
<type name="{OriginalClass}">
    <plugin name="{Name}" type="{PluginClasss}" sortOrder="{sortorder}"/>
</type>
```

**Class preference:**

The old-fashioned way of overriding classes is what we got used to, but this is slightly different... See the details at the [Inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/).

**Syntax:**

```
<preference for="{OriginalClass}" type="{OverriderClassClasss}" />
```

As per as, you want to `override` a ***function/method: Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress***

Comment: Preference method also not working for me.if any changes in my di.xmi.please specify that

Answer (score 0):

**In Model file...**

```
use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;

class AbstractAddress
{

    protected $_directoryData = null;
    protected $_eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
    Data $directoryData, Config $eavConfig
    )
    {
        $this->_directoryData = $directoryData;
        $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function aroundValidate(\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress $subject, callable $proceed)
    {

        $errors = [];
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'firstname']);
        }
        //OX:Removed  validation  related to Lastname

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getStreetLine(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'street']);
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'city']);
        }

        if ($this->isTelephoneRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'telephone']);
            }
        }

        if ($this->isFaxRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getFax(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'fax']);
            }
        }

        if ($this->isCompanyRequired()) {
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCompany(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'company']);
            }
        }
        $_havingOptionalZip = $this->_directoryData->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();
        if (!in_array(
                        $subject->getCountryId(), $_havingOptionalZip
                ) && !\Zend_Validate::is(
                        $subject->getPostcode(), 'NotEmpty'
                )
        ) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'postcode']);
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($subject->getCountryId(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'countryId']);
        }

        if ($subject->getCountryModel()->getRegionCollection()->getSize() && !\Zend_Validate::is(
                        $subject->getRegionId(), 'NotEmpty'
                ) && $this->_directoryData->isRegionRequired(
                        $subject->getCountryId()
                )
        ) {
            $errors[] = __('%fieldName is a required field.', ['fieldName' => 'regionId']);
        }

        if (empty($errors) || $subject->getShouldIgnoreValidation()) {
            return true;
        }

        return $errors;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool 
     * @since 100.2.0 
     */
    protected function isCompanyRequired()
    {
        return ($this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'company')->getIsRequired());
    }

    /**
     * @return bool 
     * @since 100.2.0 
     */
    protected function isTelephoneRequired()
    {
        return ($this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'telephone')->getIsRequired());
    }

    /**
     * @return bool 
     * @since 100.2.0 
     */
    protected function isFaxRequired()
    {
        return ($this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'fax')->getIsRequired());
    }
```

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress">
        <plugin name="aroundAddressValidation" type="XXX\OptionalLastname\Plugin\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i am facing this strange issue. i want to change the line `elseif ($regionId && !in_array($regionId, $allowedRegions, true))` but the execution is not going till that line

Comment: Can u mention the error?

Comment: no error, but the control redirects to cart page. Initially i was getting error `Please check the shipping address information. Invalid value of "533" provided for the regionId field` thats the reason i created plugin

Answer (score 0):

to override any class u need to add prefrence in di.xml, if this class is for Adminhtml create di.xml in etc -> adminhtml -> di.xml and add `

```
<preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Form" type="vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Form" />
```

`

and create same file in given directory.